What is the name of this "change" of notes?
Is there a name for when part of a song that is repeatedly sung with the same notes within the song is later sung with different notes?
For example, the notes that Hugh Jackman uses to sing the word "make" at the end of A Million Dreams are different from those used the other times that part was sung before.
This example can be seen at roughly 4:04 min to 4:09 min on this version of the song:



And out of curiosity, what notes is Hugh hitting there? I've listened to many covers of this song but no one reproduces that effect so it makes me wonder whether the notes are really high.

There’s no one special word for the situation, but there are a few that are relevant or similar. In this case, a few extra bars have been added to the melody, with a few extra chords. Hugh Jackman doesn’t get to make this decision on his own, as the band and Michelle Williams have to provide extra material too. It’s the composer’s decision.
There’s no special word for “the composer making slight additions to material that has come before.” When a composer makes large changes to the entire melody, to make a sort of new version, that’s a “variation.” But this is not a big enough change for that. The best way is just to describe it directly: the composer added a few bars this time.
If we want to talk about the music theory of the chords, it just so happens that these extra bars fall at a cadence. “Stretching out” harmonic motion is “prolongation,“ so we could call this choice a “cadential prolongation.“
You ask why Hugh Jackman is singing higher notes than initially. This is partly  because Michelle Williams is singing the melody and he’s singing harmony notes above. Sometimes this is called singing “high harmony.“ Even so, perhaps he is singing a higher harmony than in some earlier spot? (I’m not able to listen closely to the whole song right this second.) For this, again, there would be no special term, just “singing even higher than before.“
often one individual singer does get to make changes to a melody that don’t require anyone else to join in. They might be small changes, of a few notes; they might even be large, like inserting a few extra bars but expecting everyone to stop and wait while they do so, and resume the melody when they’re done. These changes “add to“ the music without fundamentally transforming it, like a decoration, so they’re called “ornamentation.“ composers can specifically write ornamentation into the notes, but if the performer does it spontaneously, it’s “improvisation.“

TL;DR
The name for the "change" is simply the higher 2nd voice.  But when you contrast the "make" melody with the preceding "take" melody, it's an afterthought / echo, frequent in both pop and classical compositions.
We can observe 2 things:

The composer intends the "make" melody as an afterthought / echo of the "take" melody (see detailed description below).  But the one you mentioned (4:02-4:10) it's a repeated variation of the "take" melody although the words is "make", so in this instance we can also call it a bridge between the original "take" melody and the original echo "make" melody.

The higher notes that Hugh sang is simply the higher 2nd voice when he sang with Michelle (common in duets), to make it less boring.  But when both sing the original afterthought "make" melody at 4:13-4:17 they sing in unison.


The "take" and the "make" melodies described in detail
By the "make" melody I mean the 3 places where "Oh, a million dreams for the world we're gonna make" (B3 D4 | E4 D4 D4  B3 B3 | E4 D4 C4 B3 B3 |) is sung. In those 3 places it functions as an afterthought / echo, sung in a subdued way about a 6th lower after the climactic "take" melody, "A million dreams is all it's gonna take" (G4 C5 B4 B4 A4 A4 | G4 A4 G4 |).  Unlike the "take" melody that ends in the tonic, this echo ends in the 3rd degree (which is fine for an afterthought).

Measures 56 to 58 (1:30-1:35) sung by Ziv (B3 D4 | E4 D4 D4  B3 B3 | E4 D4 C4 B3 B3 |), which then goes to a Verse ("There's a house ..."

Measures 110 to 112 (2:58-3:02) sung by Hugh (exact same notes), which then modulates to E minor, which is a new melody sung by Michelle "However big ... ", serving as an interlude going back to the Chorus ("'Cause ev'ry night I lie in bed ...") ending with

"A million dreams is all it's gonna take" (3:55-4:01) sung by both Hugh and Michelle.  Michelle sings the same "take" melody (G4 C5 B4 B4 A4 A4 | G4 A4 G4 |) but Hugh sings it a 3rd higher except for the last note "take" (which is a 6th higher).

"A million dreams is all it's gonna make" (4:02-4:10) but this melody is not the afterthought, but a variation of the "take" melody (or "cadential prolongation", cf @AndyBonner's answer) sung by Michelle (G4 | C5 B4 B4 G4 A4 | C5 B4 G4 A4 B4 | B4 (tied) | A4 | G4).  Hugh sings it a 3rd higher except for the last 3 notes of "make" where Michelle is going down (B4 A4 G4) but Hugh is going up (D4 F#4 G4).  (Since Hugh's voice is a male voice, it sounds an octave higher than Michelle's).

"A million dreams is all it's gonna make" (4:13-4:17) in the same subdued tone as the first two, except the notes is a "variation" of the "make" melody (B3 D4 E4 D4 C4 B3 B3) sung in unison by both Hugh and Michelle.




Complete list of voice parts
For what it's worth, here's the voice segments using this score as a guide because although it's for solo + SATB it tracks closely the original arrangement.

Ziv Zaifman (a boy singing in the "altoish" range) begins at 0:14 with B3 (measure 9) and ends at 2:30 with E4 (measure 93)

Hugh Jackman (singing in the tenor range) starts at 2:35 with D3 (measure 95) and ends at 3:02 with B2 (measure 112)

Michelle Williams (singing in the soprano range) takes over starting at 3:01 with G4 (measure 113)

Hugh joins Michelle in a duet starting at 3:25 (measure 127 but different notes) with G3: G3 G3 | A3 G3 F#3 G3 | D4 ... ending with C4

Hugh starts solo again at 3:37 with G3 (measure 134) alternating with Michelle then starts a duet (as a 2nd higher voice) with Michelle at 3:49 singing these notes starting in measure 141:
D4 | B3 C4 D4 D4 | D4 E4 F#4 D4 | E4 D4 C4 B3 

E4 (take) | E4 (tied) D4 | E4 D4 B3 C4 E4 D4 B3 C4 

D4 (make) | D4 (tied, 2 beats) F#4 (2 beats) | G4 | G4 (tied) 



Hugh in unison with Michelle starting at 4:13 (measure 155) with B2 and ends with B2


Hugh's high notes
What is the highest note that Hugh Jackman sings?
The short answer: it's a G4 which is well within a typical classical tenor's range of C3-B4.  Hear Luke Saydon singing C3 to A4 (minute 7:16 to 7:24).  In the pop music world it sounds high, but it really is not.  In this particular song, he sounds high probably because in the beginning of the song the boy voice of Ziv Zaifman uses the unusually low range of E3 to E4, needing to be notated in the F clef in measures 9-93!  G4 sounds high for him because in the beginning he keeps to the bottom of the lower range of B2 to C4.
Yes, G4 is closer toward the top end of a Tenor's compass, but not considered high for an opera singer like Placido Domingo.  Listen to Domingo performing the opening aria of the 2nd Act of La Traviata where he hits the same G4 at 0:40 as climax of the first section that ends with a quick modulation to F Major (1:00).  Then the aria suddenly modulates to Ab Major and he starts with F4 (1:01) and climaxes at Ab4 comfortably at 1:19, ending the phrase an octave lower at Ab3 at 1:33.  The aria then modulates to Eb major with increasing intensity at higher and higher notes requiring Domingo to consistently sings in the Bb3 to Ab4 range for the final phrase, again hitting the climax of Ab4 at 2:21 and 3:10.  In the same opera, the Tenor needs to hit a high Bb4 at the end of this famous song Libiamo ne' lieti calici.
G4 for a Soprano like Michelle Williams is toward the lower end.  Soprano range is B3 to C6, although hitting a C6 comfortably is quite hard even for opera singers.

Improvising, or extemporising come to mind. Or simply 'variation on a theme', which has happened with musos since music started.
